# Get Actual Image from onActivityResult and not Thumbnail Android Java

Tags: java, android

I am using onActivityResult to get an image taken from the camera intent. I would like to get the actual image and not the thumbnail. How can I do that. When I use data.getExtras().get("data") I get the thumbnail which is low quality. I do not wish to save the image locally as I will be uploading it to a server.

Camera Intent:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do that

Provide a `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `Intent`, pointing to a location where the third-party camera app can write the image.

> I do not wish to save the image locally as I will be uploading it to a server.

Then either settle for the thumbnail or write your own camera code (rather than using a third-party app).